# How can I create the detection for this javascript program of mine?

Tags: javascript

I've been building on top of an assignment we did in class and I'm stumped at the detection part.

I want my Mew to be "caught" when he stands on top of the pokeball, the player moves the keyboard to control the Mew and the pokeball randomly repositions on a time delay.

How can I create a function that will detect when the mew.gif is in overlap with the pokeball?

```
var _stage = document.getElementById("stage");
var _Mew = document.querySelector("img");
var _PokeBall = document.getElementById("PokeBall");

_stage.style.width = "800px";
_stage.style.height = "600px";
_stage.style.backgroundColor = "black";
_stage.style.marginLeft = "auto";
_stage.style.marginRight = "auto";

_Mew.style.position = "relative"; // Uses top and left from parent
_PokeBall.style.position = "relative"; // Uses top and left from parent

var leftPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;

var player = [ 400, 300 ]; // Left, Top
var PokeBall = [100, 100];// Top, Left
var uIval = setInterval(update, 22.22); // 30fps update loop

var map = [];  // empty Map Array

window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);
var Pval= setInterval(MovePokeball, 2000);

function generateMap()
{
    for (var row = 0; row < 2; row++)
    {
        for(var col = 0; col <8; col++)
        {
        console.log("In row "+row);
        }
    }
}
/*map[row] = []; // Creating new array in specified row
                for (var col = 0; col <8; col++)
                    {
                    console.log("In row "+row+"doing col"+col);
                    }
*/
function onKeyDown(event)
{
    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        case 37: // Left.
                if ( leftPressed == false )
                    leftPressed = true;
                break;
        case 39: // Right.
                if ( rightPressed == false )
                    rightPressed = true;
                break;
        case 38: // Up.
                if ( upPressed == false )
                    upPressed = true;
                break;
        case 40: // Down.
                if ( downPressed == false )
                downPressed = true;
                break;
        default:
                console.log("Unhandled key.");
                break;
    }
}

function onKeyUp(event)
{
    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        case 37: // Left.
                leftPressed = false;
                break;
        case 39: // Right.
                rightPressed = false;
                break;
        case 38: // Up.
                upPressed = false;
                break;
        case 40: // Down.
                downPressed = false;
                break;
        default:
                console.log("Unhandled key.");
                break;
    }
}

function update() // Going to run 30fps
{
    movePlayer();
    // move enemies
    // collision check
    // animate sprites
    PlayerCaught();
    render();
}

function movePlayer()
{
    if ( leftPressed == true && player[0] >= _Mew.width/2)
            player[0] -= 10;
    if ( rightPressed == true && player[0] < 800 - _Mew.width/2)
        player[0] += 10;
    if ( upPressed == true && player[1] >= _Mew.height/2 )
        player[1] -= 10;
    if ( downPressed == true && player[1] < 600 - _Mew.width/2)
        player[1] += 10;
}


function render()
{
    _Mew.style.left = player[0]-_Mew.width/2+"px";
    _Mew.style.top = player[1]-_Mew.width/2+"px";


}


function PlayerCaught()
{
    if (_PokeBall [100,100] = player [100,100])
    window.alert("Mew Has Been Captured!")


}

function MovePokeball()
{
    _PokeBall.style.left= Math.floor(Math.random()*801)+"px";
    _PokeBall.style.top= Math.floor(Math.random()*601)+"px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about **collision detection**. This is done by determining if two polygons intersect. Since your program is very simplified, I'm offering a very simplified solution. We're going to determine if the *graphics* intersect. This is not the ideal way to do it. Normally, graphics and physics are completely separated. But this will work (mostly), and hopefully it'll encourage you to continue to experiment.

First, we need the height and width of both images so we can do our geometric magic. This can be easily set in JavaScript, just like you did for `_stage`. However, you've already defined the `src` of your images elsewhere (probably in HTML), so it would be best to define the height and width there.

HTML Example:

```
<img id="PokeBall" src="pokeball.png" style="width:50px; height:50px" />
```

Note: This uses "inline CSS" which is another bad practice. But this works, and I don't want to overcomplicate simple things right now.

Now your `PlayerCaught` method has all the information it needs to do it's job, so how do we detect collisions? If we're working with rectangles, it's very simple. We just determine if any of the corners of one object are inside the other object. So how do we do that? Basically, we see if they intersect on both the X and Y axes.

Take two rectangles: `A` and `B`. Both have four edges: `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom`. The edges `top` and `bottom` are Y values, and the edges `left` and `right` are X values. The two rectangles intersect if any of the following is true:

```
(
    A.left < B.left < A.right 
    OR A.left < B.right < A.right
) AND (
    A.top < B.top < A.bottom 
    OR A.top < B.bottom < A.bottom
)
```

Translate that into JavaScript and you've got your collision detection function. To get the edges in your program, use the following:

```
function findEdges(img){
    var result = [];
    result["left"] = parseInt(img.style.left, 10);
    result["top"] = parseInt(img.style.top, 10);
    result["right"] = result["left"] + parseInt(img.style.width, 10);
    result["bottom"] = result["top"] + parseInt(img.style.height, 10);
    return result;
}
```

You can see that we are using the inline style that we set earlier for the `width` and `height` as well as the `top` and `left` you are already using for rendering.

SPOILER...

Putting all the pieces together might look like:

```
function PlayerCaught(){
    if (detectImgCollision(_PokeBall, _Mew)){
        window.alert("Mew Has Been Captured!")
    }
}

function detectImgCollision(imgA, imgB){
    var A = findEdges(imgA);
    var B = findEdges(imgB);
    return detectRectCollision(A, B);
}

function detectRectCollision(A, B){
    return (
        isBetween(A.left, B.left, A.right)
        || isBetween(A.left, B.right, A.right)
    ) && (
        isBetween(A.top, B.top, A.bottom)
        || isBetween(A.top, B.bottom, A.bottom)
    );
}

function isBetween(low, middle, high){
    return (low <= middle && middle <= high);
}
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/35pbsWz

This is the error I get when I run the code after adding in your additions.

Comment: Changed Java/HTML: 

http://dumptext.com/vci1aHdP

Thanks for the help so far by the way, while the functions are still a little over my head I can understand what they are doing and It's making me a little giddy to keep working forwards. 

I'll probably try and add a scoreboard counter and a restart game function upon capture.

Once I do all that I'll try and upgrade it so that each touch on the ball increases the capture probability by X Math.Random(1-20) so you can take hits and keep dodging for a random value.

Then of course the intervalled extra pokeballs...