# Detecting Collision Between PNG Picture and Rectangle JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program that uses a PNG picture file of a stick figure and a square. The stick figure has the ability to move across the screen. When the stick figure runs into the square, for now, I am trying to make the program log the `isOverlap` variable to the console when the PNG picture collides with the square. However, I am having trouble and wondering how exactly to do this problem? My code for my JavaScript file is below, I have code for the collision detection, but it does not seem to work properly:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = 40
var height = 40;
var x2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (canvas.width - width)) + 1;
var y2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (canvas.height - height)) + 1;

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(x2, y2, width, height);


var image = new Image();
image.src = "person.png";

var imgWidth = 100; 
var imgHeight = 100;
var x1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (canvas.width - imgWidth)) + 1;
var y1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (canvas.height - imgHeight)) + 1;

function drawPlayer() 
{
    ctx.drawImage(image, x1, y1, imgWidth, imgHeight);
}

function clearPlayer ()
{
    ctx.clearRect(x1, y1, imgWidth, imgHeight);
}

drawPlayer();

function detectCollision()
{
    var top1 = y1;
    var bottom1 = y1 + imgHeight;
    var left1 = x1;
    var right1 = x1 + imgWidth;

    var top2 = y2;
    var bottom2 = y2 + height;
    var left2 = x2;
    var right2 = x2 + width;

    var isOverlap;

    if ((left1 > right2) || (right1 < left2) || (top1 > bottom2) || (bottom1 < top2))
    {
        isOverlap = false;
    }
    else
    {
        isOverlap = true;
    }

    console.log("Overlap = " + isOverlap);
}

detectCollision();

document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from my answer to a similar question...

> So how do we detect collisions? If we're working with rectangles, it's
>   very simple. We just determine if any of the corners of one object are
>   inside the other object. So how do we do that? Basically, we see if
>   they intersect on both the X and Y axes.
>
> Take two rectangles: A and B. Both have four edges: top, left, right,
>   and bottom. The edges top and bottom are Y values, and the edges left
>   and right are X values. The two rectangles intersect if any of the
>   following is true:
>
> ```
> (
>     A.left < B.left < A.right 
>     OR A.left < B.right < A.right 
> ) AND (
>     A.top < B.top < A.bottom 
>     OR A.top < B.bottom < A.bottom 
> )
> ```

Compare that to your collision detection and you should see that you've overlooked several possibilities. Adjusting your if/else statement to mimic this logic should do the trick.

Original answer: [How can I create the detection for this javascript program of mine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263711/how-can-i-create-the-detection-for-this-javascript-program-of-mine/33265351#33265351)

Also, make sure you're continuously re-rendering and checking for collisions. You can do this in an animation loop, or you can do it in your `handleKeydown` function.